# how to remove backslash from url string using php?

Tags: php

I want to remove additional backslashes (`\`) from the path.

I have this code snippet.

```
$imagePath='/images/';
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select sid,fname,mname,lname,did,ppic from hrm_staff ");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0) {
 $response["hrm_staff"] = array();


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

     $recp = array();
     $recp["sid"]=$row["sid"];
     $fullName=$row['fname']."".$row['mname']."".$row['lname'];

     $recp["fname"]= $fullName;
     $recp["did"]=$row['did'];

     $ppic=$row['ppic'];

     $ppic=$imagePath.$ppic;
     $ppic = str_replace('\\','',$ppic);

     $recp["ppic"]= $ppic;

     array_push($response["hrm_staff"], $recp);
}

 echo json_encode($response);
```

When I `print` or `echo`, I get this output.

```
{"hrm_staff":[
    {"sid":"1","fname":"GaneshMB","did":"6","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/sb.jpg"},
    {"sid":"2","fname":"SwatiK","did":"5","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/ulogo.png"},
    {"sid":"3","fname":"KomalC","did":"2","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p1.jpg"},
    {"sid":"4","fname":"KarthikR","did":"2","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p3.jpg"},
    {"sid":"5","fname":"RenuP","did":"5","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p6.jpg"},
    {"sid":"6","fname":"RahulMA","did":"5","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p4.jpg"}
 ],"success":1,"message":"display records"}
```

Even after using `str_replace()` I am getting additional backslashes (`\`) in the image path. I am unable to find where I am making a mistake.

Please help me.

Comment: What actually are you printing? I don't see any echo statement there

Comment: `\/` is just an escaped forward slash (`/`). It is not actually a backslash.

Comment: in that ppic: column i want /images/prof_pic/sb.jpg like path but  \ is also getting printed along with that. i want to remove that

Comment: Also, please answer @BasheerAhmed's question. The output you have posted looks like JSON, but you haven't told us what you're `echo`ing or `print`ing.

Comment: sorry.. i have edited my question and added echo to it. i want to fetch the path of the image and display it in my application. but before that am trying to check whether that query works fine or not. when i print json data into brower, an additional (\) is added with that path. i want to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. ***trim($variable)*** has done the work for me.

this is what i have done and its working.

```
$imagePath='www.abc.com/hrm';
$ppic1=$row['ppic'];
$ppic21=$imagePath."/".trim($ppic1); // here trim($ppic1) removed that extra character (\) from the url.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` on your json format. This should solve the issue.

```
$a = '{"hrm_staff":[
{"sid":"1","fname":"GaneshMB","did":"6","ppic":"\/images\/     prof_pic\/sb.jpg"},
{"sid":"2","fname":"SwatiK","did":"5","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/ulogo.png"},
{"sid":"3","fname":"KomalC","did":"2","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p1.jpg"},
{"sid":"4","fname":"KarthikR","did":"2","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p3.jpg"},
{"sid":"5","fname":"RenuP","did":"5","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p6.jpg"},
{"sid":"6","fname":"RahulMA","did":"5","ppic":"\/images\/ prof_pic\/p4.jpg"}
],"success":1,"message":"display records"}';


Print_r(json_decode($a));
```

See Demo [here](https://eval.in/468042)

Comment: am sending this json data to my android application for further processing. will this work..?

Comment: ya... ask them to decode the data which is in json format.